# Percent-encoding in uri templates

Tags: templates, escaping, uri

In uri-template syntax, expansions are indicated with curly braces. Is it incorrect to url-encode (i.e. percent-encode) those when returning templated links e.g. in an API response?

```
http://foo.example.com/users/{?user_id}
```

versus

```
http://foo.example.com/users/%7B?user_id%7D
```

It seems like this paragraph of the standard may be relevant and indicate that they must **not** be escaped, but I am unsure:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570#section-1.2

> The default expression type is simple string expansion,
> wherein a single named variable is replaced by its value as a string
> after pct-encoding any characters not in the set of unreserved URI
> characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is incorrect to URL-encode URI Template tokens if the intent is to use the string as a URI template as opposed to a URI. Keep in mind that URI Templates are not URIs until they are expanded. If you encode them, it could be considered a URI and not a template. I maintain the [Handy URI Templates](https://github.com/damnhandy/Handy-URI-Templates) processor for Java and it would not be able to handle encoded tokens like this and would treat the string as a URI. Hope that helps.